# Trying to access a select function from Oracle with PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, function, plsql

Hello I am trying to access a simple function that returns the result of a select query, and when I am accessing it using PHP, it is throwing back a resource(5) at me rather than the result.

```
$connect = oci_connect('tiger','scott','host/user');
if(!$connect){
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'],ENT_QUOTES),E_USER_ERROR);
}


$qu = oci_parse($connect, 'select selectMe(:name) from dual');
$name = (string)'test1';
oci_bind_by_name($qu,":name",$name);

oci_execute($qu);

$row = oci_fetch_assoc($qu);
var_dump($row);
```

The selectMe function is pretty simple and just retrieves data from a table and returns the few rows that match the condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectMe( temp_name varchar2(100) ) 
  return SYS_REFCURSOR is  my_ret SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 open my_ret
   FOR select myTab_ID, myTab_NAME, myTab_AGE, myTab_SCORE 
         from myTab 
        where trim(myTab_name) = temp_name;
   RETURN my_ret;   
END;
```

Which is fairly simple. Now I am unable to understand why I am getting a resource(5) which is an indication of an error. The actual message I am getting when I var_dump the result is

> array(1) { ["SELECTME(:NAME)"]=>
>   resource(5) of type (oci8 statement)

Comment: SYS_REFCURSOR is not an object you return from a SELECT statement.

Comment: Well the function is working, I tested it using sqlplus and sqldeveloper. I also am not getting any errors, I only receive that resource message on a var_dump of the resource handler.

Comment: How are you testing the function?  I doubt using the code you posted

Comment: select selectMe('some name') from dual, and I receive the correct output in the script output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm **not** a PHP developer.  However, I can steal liberally from the [Oracle PHP wiki](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.oracle.com%2Fpage%2FPHP%2BOracle%2BFAQ&ei=PoU4Tb73LMK78gaUqrGtCg&usg=AFQjCNFPRu5zEl3SRt6xmfCU3L-xWqhXYQ) to guess that it would look something like

```
$conn = oci_connect('myusername', 'mypassword', 'mydb');

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "begin :rc := selectMe(:name); end;"); 
$refcur = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':rc', $refcur, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':name', 'test1');
oci_execute($stid);

oci_execute($refcur);
oci_fetch_all($refcur, $res);
var_dump($res);

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: you are a real genius!! Thank you for saving me Sir!! If you do have a moment, could you explain a little on why I would need to get that oci_new_cursor?

Comment: Just brilliant Justin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A working example for your definition of selectMe() is:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('cj', 'cj', 'localhost/xe');

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select selectMe(:name) as rc from dual"); 
$name = (string)'test1';
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":name", $name);
oci_execute($stid);
$r = oci_fetch_array($stid);

$refcur = $r['RC'];  // the returned record is the REF CURSOR which can be treated like a PHP statement resource
oci_execute($refcur);
oci_fetch_all($refcur, $res);
var_dump($res);

?>
```